# GeoServer - Store is marked as disabled but still serves the layers

Tags: gis, geoserver

The store generate an error when I tick enable and save.
Should I ignore this?  Is there a work around to fix it?

Build Information
Version
2.8.1
Git Revision
4ae4c3fe363439dc8e0d3f857f5a9c23cb2e75df
Build Date
19-Nov-2015 17:48
GeoTools Version
14.1 (rev 945972725619078375e357f8c21011999638df35)
GeoWebCache Version
1.8.0 (rev 1.8.x/b346a3aa6cc433a312c4608b218881d8509a8780)

Comment: what does the log file say? does the user running GeoServer have write permissions to the data_directory?

Comment: can't see an mention of it - yes - serves other layers set up in the same way (the only difference is the DB schema)

It is actually serving the data - just reports it as disabled

Comment: turn the logging level up to GEOTOOLS-DEV and try again